# inject class in to KendoUI web calendar days

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I want to utilize the KendoUI tooltip and Calendar currently I am able to set them up individually.

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var today = new Date(),
        events = [
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 8),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 12),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 24),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 6),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 7),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 25),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 27),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 3),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 5),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 22),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 27)
        ];
                    // create Calendar from div HTML element
                    $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
                        value: today,
                        dates: events,
                        month: {
                            // template for dates in month view
                            content: '# if ($.inArray(+data.date, data.dates) != -1) { #' +
                            '<div class="' +
                            '# if (data.value < 10) { #' +
                            "autohide-false" +
                            '# } else if ( data.value < 20 ) { #' +
                            "party" +
                            '# } else { #' +
                            "cocktail" +
                            '# } #' +
                            '">#= data.value #</div>' +
                            '# } else { #' +
                            '#= data.value #' +
                            '# } #'
                        },
                        footer: false
                    });

                        //set up tooltip
                        $(".autohide-false").kendoTooltip({
                            autoHide: false,
                            position: "top",
                            content: 'Hello there!'
                        });
                });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

Currently when I click on a day in the calendar widget the tooltip doesn't seem to show up. Any ideas why? Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Need to see your tooltip code.  There isn't enough here to tell what may be wrong.  Most importantly: Does your Javascript error console say anything?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher my tooltip code is attached above in my JS code snippet. Also no I do not see any errors in the console. The class name to inject my tooltip is "autohide-false" which I am attempting to do here "content: '# if ($.inArray(+data.date, data.dates) != -1) { #' +
                            '<div class="' +
                            '# if (data.value < 10) { #' +
                            "autohide-false" +
                            '# } else if ( data.value < 20 ) { #' +
                            "party" +"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tool tip was applied, but due to my rule in the "content:" parameter it was only showing up for some days.